# Is it possible to setup subdomain on DDNS with an internal DNS server and port forwarding?

Tags: networking, router, dns, subdomain, ddns

Situation:
I have a router which supports port forwarding and ddns and a server which is behind the router and hosts a website. I registered a ddns (`example.ddns.com`) and made the router forward port 80 to the website. Everything so far works fine.

Goal:
I want to setup a subdomain for the website (`subdomain.example.ddns.com`).

What I have done:
I setup a DNS server (using bind9) which is also behind the router. I made the router forward port 53 to this DNS server.

Here is the setup of the DNS server:

```
> named.conf.options

listen-on-v6 { none; };
listen-on port 53 {
    127.0.0.0/24;
    192.168.1.0/24;
    8.8.8.8;
};

allow-query {
    127.0.0.0/24;
    192.168.1.0/24;
    8.8.8.8;
};

allow-recursion {
    127.0.0.1;
};

allow-transfer { none; };
```

```
> named.conf.local

zone "example.ddns.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.example.ddns.com"
};
```

```
> db.example.ddns.com

@    IN    SOA    example.ddns.com.    hostmaster.example.ddns.com. (
                  [Serial, Refresh, etc....]
;
@            IN    NS     ns.example.ddns.com.
@            IN    A      127.0.0.1
@            IN    AAAA   ::1
ns           IN    A      127.0.0.1
subdomain    IN    A      127.0.0.1
```

I also have a virtualhost on the web server to serve `subdomain.example.ddns.com`.

Problem:
However no matter I nslookup/dig/request on browser from internal or external network, `subdomain.example.ddns.com` has no record.
Is there any wrong setting on the servers and router? Or Is it impossible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

This is technically possible, but will only work if the DDNS operator creates **NS records** at "example.ddns.com". Basic A records (the ones which allow resolving the example domain itself) do not create a subdomain delegation on their own.

Second, if you do this, you'll need to remove the `allow-query` limit because queries will be coming from **all** kinds of resolvers. (Using a DNS resolver is not a two-way relationship – just because you are sending your own queries to 8.8.8.8, doesn't mean queries from everyone else will be coming from 8.8.8.8.)

(And even if you do try to query your domain through 8.8.8.8 specifically, it will actually use a different address when forwarding queries to your nameserver.)

Next to that, `listen-on { 8.8.8.8 }` is nonsensical because your computer doesn't own that address; it would never receive packets sent to it. Only addresses that are directly assigned to the OS (i.e. those which show up in its `ip addr`) can be used as bind/listen addresses. (The same goes for the rest of your listen-on specification.) Easiest to just specify `any` and that's it.

Finally, you'll also need to put something more useful in your DNS zone. Just listing the localhost address (::1 and 127.0.0.1) won't work well, as each client will be told to connect to *their* "localhost". Your DNS zone needs to point to the servers' real IP addresses. (Since port forwarding is involved, at some point you might end up needing to define different "views" for inside and outside clients.)